# Redirect 401 error page directly to a menu item one level down

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-401

I got an website with **2 lvls**: `www.example.com/level1/level2` and  `www.example.com/level2`, both in the same `root directory`.

The website `www.example.com/level1/level2` is key logged. When someone is calling the site, I want them to be redirected to `www.example.com/level2`, because they can´t log in and will get a `401 error`, because they have no `password` and `id`. Its the same site, but with different articles.

So I want that if they get an `401 error page`, the user will be directly redirected to the other link.

**Example:** someone get to the site `www.example.com/banana/cherry` --> logged --> `401` --> redirect to `www.example.com/cherry`.

I've tried the following in the `.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 401 http://example.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^/banana/(.+)$ /$1 [L,QSA]
```

but it didn't work.

I appreciate any help! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Of course this doesn’t work - your RewriteCond preceding the rule demands that the request URI was just `/`.

Comment: And you should specify a relative URL for your ErrorDocument - otherwise this will cause an _external_ redirect, and especially in the case of 401 that is problematic, as the manual clearly states.